# Application crashes when working with core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

```
Unknown class CPTGraphHostingView in Interface Builder file.
2012-01-09 16:09:34.242 ChartArea[2595:207] -[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c064f0
2012-01-09 16:09:34.245 ChartArea[2595:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c064f0'
```

This is the error I am getting this evening. i am setting the class name of to CPTGraphHostingView to my uiview within interfacebuilder.

Comment: try this  in your code CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;

Comment: CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;  this is what i used in my code!

Comment: its about the interface builder which is not reading. Saying unknow class its the problem even i given proper the class in my interface Builder for the UIView to get the Bar chart graph

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

> Select your project from the navigator panel in Xcode and then
>   highlight the Build Settings tab. Filter the settings or locate ‘Other
>   Linker Flags’ from this list and then add -ObjC -all_load to these
>   settings

(From here: http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/)

Comment: Typical case of 'RTFM'. I was wondering what those linker flags were for...the documentation of CorePlot really is the pits...ah well.

Comment: @kiran, this answer should be approved.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your view in ViewController is not a type of CPTGraphHostingView, so the view fails to cast.

It can fixed by creating exact instance of CPTGraphHostingView then add it to the ViewController's view.

```
CGRect frame = [[self view] bounds];

CPTGraphHostingView* graphHost = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[[self view] addSubview: graphHost];
```

Hope this help.