# Unknown class CPTGraphHostingView in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-plot

I'm using new core plot version. I'm stuck in this error. I googled and went through many same question on stackoverflow, but didn't find solution. I want to draw bar chart, I have done all the necessary setting and coding require to display bar chart, but got stuck in this error. I have checked the CPTGraphHostingView on view on XIB side. Did other linker flag seting and also wrote barChartView.hostedGraph = barChart. Target Memembership option is also checked.
Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8914179/326017

Answer (score 9):

Provided you have your setup right with the core plot header files and the core-plot library included in your project. Here is what I did to fix the problem.

In your target `Build Settings`, set the linker flags to:

```
-objC -force_load "core plot library name"
```

`-all_load` is not needed if you are using 4.2+ version.

The reason for `-force_load` is that `-all_loa`d was trying to compile all the other libraries that I had in my project.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 5.1 - Build Settings - Linker - Other Linker Flags - -ObjC

I had the same error, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your header search path setup correctly? There are instructions posted on the [Core Plot wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications).

Comment: I met the same error. Project compiles and links with Core Plot without any error. But in runtime it logs the mentioned error in console.