# -[UIView setHostedGraph:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, core-plot

I am trying to use Core Plot to draw a graph, but I my graph view is instantiated as a `UIView` *even though I've set it as `CPTGraphHostingView` in interface builder*:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
usersGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:usersGraphView.frame];
usersGraphView.hostedGraph = usersGraph;
```

Why would that happen?

Comment: Can you show the crash log please.

Comment: Indeed; demonstrate why you think it's a `UIView` and not a Core Plot custom view.

Comment: @Fogmeister @trojanfoe because it says so in the crash log (the title). it would say CPTGraphHostingView if it was an instance of that class. here is the output: `2014-05-06 10:41:21.362 TanisalimAdmin[732:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156d5930'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing on and off in Interface Builder trying everything again and again, I've started to search more on StackOverflow and I've stumbled upon this question: [Application crashes when working with core plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787164/application-crashes-when-working-with-core-plot/8914179#8914179)

Pretty weird, but it wasn't and IB issue (I was sure I was doing the right thing in IB, I've done it a thousand times before), but a linker issue. I don't know why, but I had to add `-ObjC` to linker flags, and it worked.

Comment: Awesome! I have CorePlot inside my own Framework and I had already decided that Framework was broken... I lost hope. Thank you!

Comment: Really, it's because of the -ObjC linker flags. My additional mistake was to make the first O of -ObjC as lowercase 'o'. :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that it is strange?

For **UIView** to have `setHostedGraph`

```
-[UIView setHostedGraph:]
```

I think you have dragged the `IBOutlet` for that UIView into the custom class file before adding the `CPTGraphHostingView`on the identity inspector. Remove the `IBOutlet` and drag again.

I downloaded the sample project from corePlot. Make sure that the `IBOutlet` is **CPTGraphHostingView**.

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't affect the type of view that is created.  Even if the `IBOutlet` was `UIView *` then a Core Plot view would be created if that's what is set-up in IB.

Comment: IBOutlet MUST be CPTGraphHostingView. If not, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Not true.  How about if you wanted to create a custom view within a NIB that is loaded by an standard (not subclassed) `UIViewController`?  The `UIViewController.view` will be `UIView` but the view itself can be a subclassed `UIView` instance, set-up within IB.  The same applies here.  Of course you *should* have the `IBOutlet` set correctly in order make the compiler happy, but it will not cause the loaded view to be a generic `UIView` rather than a custom view.

Comment: hm... I rarely use NIB. Started to train my iOS skills from using storyboard. I guess it might be something I do not know then.

Comment: It was a linker issue, see my answer.